# Docker container don't start

Tags: linux, docker, debian, s390x

Hi I've got a problem with docker. I'm using it on s390x Debian, everything was working fine but now i can't start my containers. Old containers are working but when i create new container using for example: `docker run ubuntu` then i'm trying `docker start [CONTAINER]` my container don't start. When i use `docker ps -a` I've got all of my containers, but after when I use `docker ps` i can't see my new container. As you can see on scr. I created container with name practical_spence and ID 3e8562694e9f but when i use `docker start`, it's not starting. Please help.
[image: scr]

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including for example the Dockerfile you're using to build your image?  (The standard `ubuntu` image doesn't have very much in it and there wouldn't generally be a reason to run it directly.)  In practical use I've found it very unusual to start a stopped container; can you `docker rm` the stopped container, then `docker run` a new one?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not specify a CMD or entrypoint to run, the default is used which is set to `"bash"`. But you are not running the container in interactive terminal mode, so the bash just exits. Run:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest
```

to attach the running container to you terminal. Or specify the command you want to run in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You container did start but exit instantly as it has nothing to do. You can start like this `docker run -d ubuntu sleep infinity`. Then use `docker ps` to see the running container. You can of course exec into it to do something `docker exec -it <container> bash`. You can stop it `docker stop <container>`. Re-start it `docker start <container>`. Finally delete (stopped) it as you don't need it anymore `docker container rm <container>`.